# ng-repeat with angular ui select initialize

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, initialization, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have ui select inside ng-repeat and the result is going to mongodb. Below is the html code:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in colorObj.tagsCategories">
    <span>{{category.name}}: </span>
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="selected[$index]">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select tags">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="tag in category.tags">{{tag.name}}</ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

Inside controller i set $scope.selected to be inside colorObj like below:

```
$scope.colorObj=getColorObj();
$scope.selected=$scope.colorObj.selected;
```

Function `getColorObj()` return object of color from mongodb, and i dont modify `$scope.colorObj.selected` anywhere else. On console.log() i see that `$scope.colorObj.selected` get saved correctly inside database and get puller from server, but when in comes to controller which contain ui-select`$scope.colorObj.selected` get cleaned to empty. Is there any option in ui-select i missed in documentation that is responsible for initialize or i just do something wrong?